# python + pandas: convert class to json, but ignore dataframe member

Tags: python, pandas

[Was able to reproduce the issue, so updating..]
I am using Json to convert an object instance to JSON.  The object has a member property that is of type pandas.DataFrame (which i don't care to serialize, but do want to keep a reference to).  The following snippet shows the issue.  The first serialization to json works, but the second produces an error:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, df, title, description, some_arr):
        self.title = title
        self.descr = description
        self.arr = some_arr
        self.df = df

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5), columns = ['A','B','C','D','E'])
    mc1 = MyClass(df, 'title', 'descr', [1,2,3,4])
    json_data = json.dumps(mc1, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)   #Works Fine

    df = df[['A']]
    mc2 = MyClass(df, 'title', 'descr', [1,2,3,4])
    json_data = json.dumps(mc2, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)   #DOES NOT WORK
```

The second case (after filtering the DF), produces the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'weakref' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

Why is this and how do i resolve or get the second case working?

Comment: the only way i could solve tis was to do create a new dataframe:   df = pd.DataFrame(df[['A']]).   I would like to understand why it is happening though.